# vbscript Click on an element of a navigation tree

Tags: html, vbscript, click

I am trying to click on a element of a navigation tree on a website. To do it I use the following code

```
divNavTree.document.GetElementById("action|1").Click
```

This results in nothing happening. When I try this `divNavTree.document.GetElementById("action|1").InnerHTML` I am able to see the code behind it:

```
<li id="action|1">
    <a target="content" style="margin-left:13px;" href="/interface/action/default.asd">
    <img src="/style/nav/action.gif" class="treeImage">
    <span>Action</span></a>
</li>
```

How can I click (or at least select) this element? Or, alternatively, how can I open the link under this button, taking into consideration that it is supposed to be opened in a frame rather than take the full browser window.

This is a script that is supposed to automate navigation on a webpage, I have no influence on the HTML at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not click the `li` element. Get the `firstChild` of your element (the `<a ...`) and click it